# Trying to select a column by matching a row value but return the value of another row in that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, lookup

I have a pandas dataframe

```
       field          sev         iso         des 
0  shortname          sev         iso         des 
1   fullname  Sevoflurane  Isoflurane  Desflurane
2        id             0           1           2
3 colorname          Gold Dark Magenta Royal Blue
4  colorHex       #FFD700     #8B008B     #4169E1
5       mac           2.1        1.15         5.8
```

I am trying to find the right pandas syntax to search for the column where the 'id' row matches value 1 and return that same columns 'mac' value

if can select the column with

```
c = df.loc['id'] = 1
```

now I try to get the columns 'mac' value which dosnt work

```
_mac = csv_rx_df.at[c, 'mac']
```

How do I do this?

Comment: looks like your DF should really be transposed - that's guessing that you want 2.1 for id = 1?

Comment: `df.iloc[5][df.iloc[2] == 1]`. Try this slicing condition and see if it works.

Comment: Isoflurane 'mac' = 1.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#set 'field' as index
df = df.set_index('field')
#get the column where id row equals "1", and subsequently,
#get the value for 'mac'
df.loc['mac',df.loc['id',:].eq("1")]

iso    1.15
Name: mac, dtype: object
```

Comment: df.set_index('field', inplace=True)
result = df.loc['mac', df.loc['id' ,:].eq("1")]     
worked fine, now I'll make a def() function, 
thanks again to everybodies help

Comment: Don’t forget to upvote and accept as answer if it works for u